# I still don't understand regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have this piece of code but have no idea what it is supposed to be matching. I have looked at many different sites to try and learn the keywords, but I just don't understand regex.

```
string key = @"^(.*)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*$";
Match value = Regex.Match(line, key);
```

Comment: it just captures the key, value pair into two separate groups. Here http://regex101.com/r/mL4sH7/4 see the explanation at the right side. If you don't want to capture the last following spaces then add a `?` inside the second capturing group like `(.*?)`

Comment: http://regex101.com can explain a regex given a regex.

Comment: When in doubt use [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dN4rD1/1) and its wonderful "explanation" panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks for the start of a line (`^`), finds any number of characters (`(.*)`), followed by some whitespace (`\s*`) an equal sign (`=`) some more whitespace (`\s*`) and any number of characters (`(.*)`) and the end of line (`$`)

Some valid example lines:

```
a=a
abc   =   xyz
value=5
```

etc

Comment: I was able to go back to the file it is taking a line from and see what it is talking about now thank you very much for your help. Now I'm just really confused why he did it this way.

Comment: he did it because it is an easy way to parse a line.  parsing by hand and getting as much error checking would probably take about 10 lines instead of 2.

Comment: yea I got to see the actual file he would be using and it makes allot of since why he did it that